# Using MPI_Type_Create_Subarray in FORTRAN 90

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90, array-splice

This is related to the earlier thread on "Using MPI_Send/Recv to handle chunk of multi-dim array in Fortran 90". My array is real and 3-dim say 5 by 5 by 5, i.e x(1:5,1:5,1:5) If I want to send the following part of my array say

```
x(2:3,2:5,4:5)
```

to Proc 1 from 0, I am using the following test program

```
program mpi
implicit none
include "mpif.h"

integer :: ierr,myid,nprocs,status(mpi_status_size),i,j,k,&
&          starts(3),newsize(3),oldsize(3)
real    :: x(1:5,1:5,1:5),y(1:5,1:5,1:5),z(2:3,2:5,4:5)
integer :: arr

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,nprocs,ierr)

if(myid == 0) then
  x = 0.0
  call random_number(x)
  starts = (/2,2,4/)
  newsize = (/2,4,2/)
  oldsize = (/5,5,5/)
  call mpi_type_create_subarray(3,oldsize,newsize,starts,mpi_order_fortran, &
  & mpi_real,arr,ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(arr,ierr)
  call mpi_send(x,1,arr,1,1,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
  do i = 2,3
    do j = 2,5
      do k = 4,5
        print*,'#1',x(i,j,k)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
  print*,' '
else
  y = 0.0
  call mpi_recv(z,16,mpi_real,0,1,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
  do i = 2,3
    do j = 2,5
      do k = 4,5
        print*,'#2',z(i,j,k)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
endif

call mpi_finalize(ierr)

stop
end
```

I am getting runtime errors related to the 'start' array. It's elements must be 0 or 1. What am I missing here? What is the correct form for this? I could not find a FORTRAN example for using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard specifies that the `array_of_starts` (your `starts`) starts indexing at zero, not at one! So if a Fortran numbering starts at one, you have to subtract `1`. Consequently, your `starts` array should be `(/  1, 1, 3 /)`.

From the [MPI 3.0 Standard, Ch. 4.1.3](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf):

> Advice to users. In a Fortran program with arrays indexed starting
>   from 1, if the starting coordinate of a particular dimension of the
>   subarray is N, then the entry in array_of_starts for that dimension is
>   n-1.  (End of advice to users.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. What happens if an array starts from a negative index say for the parent array x(-n:n,-m:m), I want to send the chunk x(-2:0,:)? What should be the start array now?

Comment: @Madhurjya, the offset of `-2` from `-n` is `(-2)-(-n) = n-2`. For the second dimension the offset is `0`.

Comment: Thank you both Alexander and Hristo! The discussion did help me a lot.